# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'face_recognition', but i installed face-recognition module

Tags: python, face-recognition

I have no code yet

I installed face recognition library (as I think)
if i write "pip freeze" I get this:

click==8.1.3

colorama==0.4.5

dlib==19.24.0

face-recognition==1.4.0

face-recognition-models==0.3.0

numpy==1.23.3

Pillow==9.2.0

But when i try to import face recognition I have this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'face_recognition'. I'm new in python, if you could help me I will be grateful
[this is error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPiXE.png)

Comment: what are the commands that you are using to install the modules and what (IDE or terminal) are you running the code in that gives you this error?

Comment: Can you screenshot the project structure?

Comment: Check either you've installed face_recognition and then run your script under the same enviroment.